# Java Generics - how to access subclass parameters

Tags: java

My sample code structure is like this. There is one parent class Building and one subclass House.

**Buiding**

```
public class Building {
    private String name;
    private int noOfHouses; 
}
```

**House**

```
public class House extends Building {
    private String houseNumber;
}
```

I want to write a generic method so that i can access the subclass method also.
something like this.

```
public <T> void construct(T a){
    System.out.println(a.getHouseNumber());
}
```

Please help.

Comment: I would strongly advise against that. It's a bad design and down the road it will create more problems. A relatively better alternatives would be to define an abstract method in the parent and override it in the children.

Comment: Where do you want to write that static method?

Comment: why not make `T` a `House` instead, no reason for generics as of now.

Comment: is `getHouseNumber()` a method of class `House`? (Maybe by using Lombock)

Comment: @slartidan: Yes,it part of House sub-class.

Answer (score 1):

In fact your example does not show the need of generics. You can use:

```
public static void construct(House a){
    System.out.println(a.getHouseNumber());
}
```

The same thing, unnecessarily complicated to use generics would also work fine:

```
public static <T extends House> void construct(T a){
    System.out.println(a.getHouseNumber());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics have nothing to do with this problem. Java provides you with the facility of RunTimePolymorphism, but you can't invoke child's specific method using parent reference.

Consider the following case:

```
Building b = new House();  //Fine
b.getHouseNumber() // Compiler will  be happy only if getHouseNumber is in Building.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and shouldn't do that. It's a bad idea to make parent classes aware of child classes' own concrete methods.

You can use a bounded parameter, if this method is in `House`, or any other class that doesn't complicate the parent/child relationship:

```
public static <T extends House> void construct(T a){
    System.out.println(a.getHouseNumber());
}
```

The same thing can be done if the parent is abstract, as suggested above:

```
public abstract class Building {

    private String name;

    private int noOfHouses; 

    public abstract String getHouseNumber();

    public static <T extends Building> void construct(T a){
        System.out.println(a.getHouseNumber());
    }
}
```

Note that the parent doesn't have to be abstract, as long as it's OK with your design

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ernest Kiwele, but if you want to access a method that will be part of a subclass you can override a method in each subclass

```
abstract class Building{
    private String name;
    private int noOfHouses;

    public abstract String getHouseNumber();

    public void construct(){
        System.out.println( getHouseNumber() );
    }
}

public class House extends Building{

    private String houseNumber = "houseNumber";

    public String getHouseNumber(){
       return this.houseNumber;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
      House h = new House();
      h.construct();
    }
}
```